# Castle.Windsor doesn't run installers using FromAssembly.InThisApplication unless the assembly is referenced in code

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I've got 2 projects, one is a MVC site, the other a class library. The MVC site references the class library.

I have an implementation of `IWindsorInstaller` in the MVC site and the class library.  There is no code in the MVC site that directly references any classes defined in the class library, they are all implementations of interfaces defined elsewhere.

In the MVC site, in app start I'm doing the usual

```
var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
container.Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication());
```

This does not call the installer in the class library.  However if I do this

```
container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<ClassFromTheClassLibrary>());
```

The installer gets called twice.  It seems that Castle requires an actual in-code reference to the other assembly for the `InThisApplication` to pick it up.  I can fix this by just doing this:

```
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<ClassFromTheClassLibrary>());
```

but I was hoping to not have to reference the other assembly directly.

*Update* The namespaces are:

- MVC app is MyApp.OnlineProducts.Service
- class library is MyApp.Individuals.Service

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you name your assemblies as per required naming convention. If your main application assembly name is MyApp.exe, you should name other class libraries like MyApp.*.dll (e.g. FirstClassLibrary.Whatever.dll and MyApp.SecondClassLibrary.dll) and Windsor will pick up all of the related libraries abiding the naming convention. See [this page](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Whats-New-In-Windsor-3&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) on Windsor documentation that explains this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

FromAssembly.InThisApplication() matches assemblies using the calling assembly as a prefix. Calling from MyApp.dll will match MyApp.Core.dll & MyApp.Stuff.dll.

So, renaming your class library may be an option?

Otherwise, you might want to use:
 FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("c:\dir","*.dll"))
to locate your "component assemblies".

== UPDATE ==
My comments are misleading.

FromAssembly.InThisApplication() only walks assemblies referenced from the calling assembly.

Comment: So why does it work when I add a reference to the assembly in code?

Comment: You need to identify which assemblies to find the IWindsorInstaller(s). FromAssembly.Containing<> is just another way to find an assembly.
You need to define how you want assemblies found. If you want ZERO code references, then by a dir & filename pattern is pretty much the only way to go.

Comment: But shouldn't `FromThisApplication` work when both assemblies have the same first part of the name?

Comment: You've listed the namespaces, double check the assembly names.

Comment: Matching is based on the Assembly.FullName of the assembly calling FromAssembly.InThisApplication().

Comment: Yep, they both start with the same thing

Answer (score 1):

To get Current executing Assembly, follow the other answer.

```
public class ServiceIoC
{
    private static IWindsorContainer _container;
    private static int initstatus = 0;

    public static IWindsorContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (_container == null && initstatus == 0)
            {
                initstatus = 1;
                _container = new WindsorContainer();
                _container.Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            }

            return _container;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the other answers here, when building a web app / wcf service, make sure the class calling

```
var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
container.Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication());
```

does not live in the App_Code folder. This is an easy mistake to make, since the Windsor bootstrap process relies on the `AppInitialize()` method to be somewhere in App_Code, but having the actual bootstrap code in the App_Code folder makes it live in a separate App_Code assembly, breaking the assembly prefix conversion mentioned here.